# How to generate /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt for embedded Linux?

Tags: linux, openssl, certificates

I am working on an embedded Linux (kernel-5.10.24), and there is a web application running in this system.
The web application failed with `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt no such file or directory`.
Since this is an embedded system, the rootfs in target is built in host, and I don't know how to generate the `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` for the target.

Comment: It's just a file. How do you copy other files into the embedded filesystem?

Comment: I copied the file from my development host to the target, but the web application still failed. So I am not sure if it is the right way to do that.